# What's the difference between these two SpriteKit functions?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I don't know what's the difference between these two functions.

First:

```
coin.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: -146.115, duration: 0))
```

Second:

```
coin.position.y = -146.115
```

Comment: See the documentation of SKAction here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417768-moveto. In short SKAction animates the sprite object to the new position over the duration specified.

Answer (score 4):

The SKAction will not be processed until the next frame-- directly after `update`. If you call `.run` after `didEvaluateActions`, your position will not be updated, and you may encounter bugs due to that.

The second line of code will take place immediately, regardless of your position in the SK loop.

Example, if you are using physics, and call `.run(.move(` on something in `didBegin(contact`, and then are expecting that sprite to have moved already by `didEnd(contact)`, then you will have problems. In that situation, you want to manually adjust `.position` instead of using an action.

[image]

Secondly, the `.run` command is also less performant, because it requires the initialization of an SKAction object, which is somewhere between 20-30% slower than just adjusting the position manually.

Granted, that amount of difference doesn't add up to much, but in complicated scenes it could be the difference between getting everything done in 16ms (60fps) or not.

Third, as others have mentioned, there is the `forDuration` parameter, which allows you to animate the movement over a period of time.. say, 2 seconds, or however long you want.

Answer (score 2):

`SKAction.moveTo()` has a `duration` parameter, which is there, because it is an animated version of changing a node's position over the specified time interval. On the other hand, changing the position of a node doesn't animate the movement.

Comment: hey there, there is actually a bit more to it than just the parameter and the animation. Check out my answer if you'd like :)

Answer (score 0):

In first line you are using your coin class object and accessing function run through it's object.

```
coin.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: -146.115, duration: 0))
```

In second line coin class object accessing it's property `position.y` and assign it float value.

```
coin.position.y = -146.115
```

Hope u got it!!!

Comment: hey there, thanks for contributing to SO. Please see my answer for a more detailed description of the differences :)